# What is the meaning of the phrase "sixth-place player"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across it while reading an article on economy yet failed to decipher its meaning in given context and a Google search was neither effective.

Here's the exact sentence:
"It was almost laughable for Philip Morris - as **the sixth-place player** with 9 % market share in the 1950s - to take on the goal of defeating Goliath RJ Reynolds Tobacco Company and becomming number one".

Comment: Presumably, they were the sixth largest tobacco company in the 1950s (*player* = *competitor*).

Comment: It is greatly preferable if folks include a link to the source they are quoting. This is so we can check the greater context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mick pointed out in his comment, in this statement the author is considering the marketplace as a game, and the companies competing against each other as players in the game.  If you then consider the total money spent by customers as "100% of the market", then Philip Morris, who was receiving 9% of that money, was in sixth place; that is, there were 5 other companies who sold more than they did.  In particular, R.J. Reynolds Tobacco Company was in first place, and was probably several times larger than Philip Morris at the time.

To pull some random numbers out of my hat, the company standings may have looked something like this:

- 41%: R.J. Reynolds Tobacco Company
- 15%: Competitor company number 2
- 12%: Competitor company number 3
- 10%: Competitor company number 4
- 10%: Competitor Company number 5
- 9%: Philip Morris
- 3%: A bunch of other very minor competitors combined

With 5 companies ahead of it, Philip Morris is the **6th-place player** in the market, and is clearly very far behind the leader, who is selling more than four times as much as they are.  So, setting a target of increasing their sales by a factor of 5 (or, alternatively, of stealing half of R.J. Reynolds' business) is a very ambitious, aggressive target; one might say it is "laughable" because of how unlikely it is that they could achieve such a thing.

Comment: Exactly, and investigation of the greater context shows that this is the intended usage. See especially *Philip Morris did rise from  sixth to first and beat RJ Reynolds worldwide*, which occurs a page later than the sentence given by Tatyana. Ref: Pages 161-162 *Delivering Results: A New Mandate for Human Resource Professionals* 
By David Ulrich.

Answer (score -2):

**Five people play per team on court in basketball.**

I believe the reference here means that Philip Morris was so small in their market penetration as to be not even considered in the game. it's a hyperbolic introduction of PM to set it up as the "David" for the "Goliath" part later in the sentence.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_man):

> The **sixth man** in basketball is a player who is not a starter but comes off the bench much more often than other reserves, often being the first player to be substituted in.

Comment: It's unlikely that basketball is involved. It's just a coincidence that PM was the sixth largest tobacco company. If PM had been just behind another company that was the sixth largest, the quote would have read "as the seventh-place player". By the way, I am not a downvoter.

Comment: People should google first, then downvote.  I didn't know this, but it turns out the *sixth man* is well established.

Comment: @aparente001 That's great, but the quote doesn't reference the "sixth man"; "sixth-place player" is not the same thing at all.  (Especially since the 5 companies ranked above Philip Morris do not form a team.)

Comment: @Hellion - See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_man_(fans) which was referenced in the wikipedia link I added to the answer: "This article is about the group of basketball team supporters. For the player, see Sixth man."  The participants in the court in a basketball are *players*.

Comment: -1 despite comments and edit by @aparente001 the phrase *sixth-place player* does not refer to the *sixth man* in basketball.

Comment: @Hellion - I take it back.  I've read a bit more about this and have decided it's probably just a coincidence.  (Even though I did form the impression the big tobacco producers, including Philip Morris, were probably collaborating on their strategy vis-à-vis growing health danger evidence.  And even though Philip Morris was sponsoring sports teams to get their marketing message across when the government moved to limit regular advertising.)  The quoted article is from the mid 90's and I suspect the sixth man or sixth player is more recent.